# failed to run custom build command for `torch-sys v0.8.0`

Tags: rust, pytorch

I am following along with this [tutorial](https://sachaarbonel.medium.com/how-to-build-a-semantic-search-engine-in-rust-e96e6378cfd9) and when I get to attempt running it I have trouble w/ 'torch-sys'. When I use `cargo run` or `cargo run --target x86_64-apple-darwin` I get the following error message.

```
Compiling torch-sys v0.8.0
The following warnings were emitted during compilation:

warning: clang: warning: -Wl,-rpath=/Users/macabe/semantic-search/target/debug/build/torch-sys-3f4db2fcb77e7c54/out/libtorch/libtorch/lib: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]cargo:warning=clang: warning: -Wl,-rpath=/Users/macabe/semantic-search/target/debug/build/torch-sys-3f4db2fcb77e7c54/out/libtorch/libtorch/lib: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
warning: libtch/torch_api.cpp:1:9: fatal error: 'torch/csrc/autograd/engine.h' file not found
warning: #include<torch/csrc/autograd/engine.h>
warning:         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
warning: 1 error generated.

error: failed to run custom build command for `torch-sys v0.8.0`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/Users/macabe/semantic-search/target/debug/build/torch-sys-e88d97111c03df15/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TORCH_CUDA_VERSION
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=LIBTORCH
  cargo:rustc-link-search=native=/Users/macabe/semantic-search/target/debug/build/torch-sys-3f4db2fcb77e7c54/out/libtorch/libtorch/lib
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=libtch/torch_api.cpp
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=libtch/torch_api.h
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=libtch/torch_api_generated.cpp.h
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=libtch/torch_api_generated.h
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=libtch/stb_image_write.h
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=libtch/stb_image_resize.h
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=libtch/stb_image.h
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=LIBTORCH_CXX11_ABI
  TARGET = Some("aarch64-apple-darwin")
  OPT_LEVEL = Some("0")
  HOST = Some("aarch64-apple-darwin")
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXX_aarch64-apple-darwin
  CXX_aarch64-apple-darwin = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXX_aarch64_apple_darwin
  CXX_aarch64_apple_darwin = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_CXX
  HOST_CXX = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXX
  CXX = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXXFLAGS_aarch64-apple-darwin
  CXXFLAGS_aarch64-apple-darwin = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXXFLAGS_aarch64_apple_darwin
  CXXFLAGS_aarch64_apple_darwin = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_CXXFLAGS
  HOST_CXXFLAGS = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXXFLAGS
  CXXFLAGS = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  DEBUG = Some("true")
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("aes,crc,dit,dotprod,dpb,dpb2,fcma,fhm,flagm,fp16,frintts,jsconv,lor,lse,neon,paca,pacg,pan,pmuv3,ras,rcpc,rcpc2,rdm,sb,sha2,sha3,ssbs,vh")
  running: "c++" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-g" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "-arch" "arm64" "-I" "/Users/macabe/semantic-search/target/debug/build/torch-sys-3f4db2fcb77e7c54/out/libtorch/libtorch/include" "-I" "/Users/macabe/semantic-search/target/debug/build/torch-sys-3f4db2fcb77e7c54/out/libtorch/libtorch/include/torch/csrc/api/include" "-Wl,-rpath=/Users/macabe/semantic-search/target/debug/build/torch-sys-3f4db2fcb77e7c54/out/libtorch/libtorch/lib" "-std=c++14" "-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1" "-o" "/Users/macabe/semantic-search/target/debug/build/torch-sys-3f4db2fcb77e7c54/out/libtch/torch_api.o" "-c" "libtch/torch_api.cpp"
  running: "c++" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-g" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "-arch" "arm64" "-I" "/Users/macabe/semantic-search/target/debug/build/torch-sys-3f4db2fcb77e7c54/out/libtorch/libtorch/include" "-I" "/Users/macabe/semantic-search/target/debug/build/torch-sys-3f4db2fcb77e7c54/out/libtorch/libtorch/include/torch/csrc/api/include" "-Wl,-rpath=/Users/macabe/semantic-search/target/debug/build/torch-sys-3f4db2fcb77e7c54/out/libtorch/libtorch/lib" "-std=c++14" "-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1" "-o" "/Users/macabe/semantic-search/target/debug/build/torch-sys-3f4db2fcb77e7c54/out/libtch/fake_cuda_dependency.o" "-c" "libtch/fake_cuda_dependency.cpp"
  cargo:warning=clang: warning: -Wl,-rpath=/Users/macabe/semantic-search/target/debug/build/torch-sys-3f4db2fcb77e7c54/out/libtorch/libtorch/lib: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]cargo:warning=clang: warning: -Wl,-rpath=/Users/macabe/semantic-search/target/debug/build/torch-sys-3f4db2fcb77e7c54/out/libtorch/libtorch/lib: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]

  cargo:warning=libtch/torch_api.cpp:1:9: fatal error: 'torch/csrc/autograd/engine.h' file not found
  cargo:warning=#include<torch/csrc/autograd/engine.h>
  cargo:warning=        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  exit status: 0
  cargo:warning=1 error generated.
  exit status: 1

  --- stderr


  error occurred: Command "c++" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-g" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "-arch" "arm64" "-I" "/Users/macabe/semantic-search/target/debug/build/torch-sys-3f4db2fcb77e7c54/out/libtorch/libtorch/include" "-I" "/Users/macabe/semantic-search/target/debug/build/torch-sys-3f4db2fcb77e7c54/out/libtorch/libtorch/include/torch/csrc/api/include" "-Wl,-rpath=/Users/macabe/semantic-search/target/debug/build/torch-sys-3f4db2fcb77e7c54/out/libtorch/libtorch/lib" "-std=c++14" "-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1" "-o" "/Users/macabe/semantic-search/target/debug/build/torch-sys-3f4db2fcb77e7c54/out/libtch/torch_api.o" "-c" "libtch/torch_api.cpp" with args "c++" did not execute successfully (status code exit status: 1).
```

I have uninstalled/reinstalled pytorch and upadted conda. Any ideas on what to do for this?

Comment: You need to install the Torch development package. I don't know what it's called exactly on MacOS, but on Debian that would be `libtorch3-dev`.